# Extracting Variables and storing as a separate file out of watson

Tags: variables, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I want to be able to store context variables into a text file. Im using this code:

```
"context" : {
    "number_extract" : "<? input.text.extract('[\\d]+',0) ?>"
}
```

to extract variables into and store in context variable. I want to extract variables completely out of watson and into a a folder on my computer.
I also know you can make a database driven bot using this:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html#build-a-database-driven-slackbot

This will only store variables into the database but i want the variables extracted and put into a file out of watson.

Comment: Where is the app that interfaces with Watson Assistant running? Does it have access to your local computer?

Comment: ive deployed my watson assistant to slack. I do not know about it having access to my local computer and how do you let it have access to the computer.

Comment: So another question is how to allow a cloud-based system access to your local machine. What are the security requirements?

Comment: Um i do not know how to allow a cloud-based system to access my computer but i do think its possible. Downloading ans storing the variables in a text file, can it be done in IBM Watson or i do have to do it slack?

Comment: You could code up such functionality, e.g., a download button in Slack that is driven by Watson Assistant.

Comment: Yes maybe something like that. But how do you extract and store these variables into a text file in slack? Do you have any references or could send any links that might be helpful?